# Adding a Next and Previous Button

Tags: infopath

This article was very helpful, but would also like to include a previous button, is it possible?

[Adding a "next" Button to displayform.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96231/adding-a-next-button-to-displayform-aspx#new-answer)